# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object in Turtle module

Tags: python

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

import random

from random import randint, choice

t.colormode(255)

tim = t.Turtle()


def random_color():
    r = randint(1, 255)

    g = randint(1, 255)

    b = randint(1, 255)

    color = (r, g, b)

    return random_color()

directions = [0, 90, 180, 270]

tim.pensize(15)

tim.speed("fast")

for _ in range(200):

    tim.color(random_color())

    tim.forward(30)

    tim.setheading(choice(directions))


screen = t.Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method `random_color()`, just return `color` not the method itself. That will lead to an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

- You should return `color` not `random_color()` itself, otherwise it will be a infinite recursion

```
def random_color():
    r = randint(1, 255)
    g = randint(1, 255)
    b = randint(1, 255)
    color = (r, g, b)
    return color
```

- or you just return the result with inline variable.

```
def random_color():
    return (random.randint(1, 255),random.randint(1, 255),random.randint(1, 255))
```